# Can an inline or constexpr function be defined multiple times in a program?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am reading C++ Primer book. I find it really interesting and easy to understand for a beginner like me. But when I reached this topic:

"Put inline and constexpr Functions in Header Files"
it is said:

> Unlike other functions, inline and constexpr functions may be defined multiple times in the program. After all, the compiler needs the definition, not just the declaration, in order to expand the code. However, all of the definitions of a given inline or constexpr must match exactly. As a result, inline and constexpr functions normally are defined in headers.

Can someone please explain it to me. I find it a bit difficult to understand. I am learning on my own.

As I guess There is what is called "ODR" one-definition-rule. But what does he mean with "an inline or constexpr function can be defined multiple times in the program"?.

If someone explain with an example I'll be deeply appreciating him. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`inline` and `constexpr` are allowed to partially violate the ODR rule: Each .cpp file that uses the function must have one exactly identical copy of the function. This allows you to put small methods in a header, so that every .cpp file sees the same code, so each cpp file's copy is identical.

Comment: To be pedantic, inline functions are not allowed to "violate" ODR. Rather, it is not an ODR violation to define them in multiple TU's. The distinction is not only technical, but your wording may also be misleading, since defining an inline function more than once within a TU is still an ODR violation, and it is not allowed.

Comment: `An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used. (C++11 3.2/3)`. I guess you didn't mean `allowed to violate the ODR rule`.

Comment: What eerorika said. It is not an ODR violation, not even partially, for it is the ODR that literally defines this as valid. Don't let the name fool ya. Effectively said rule states that lexically matching definitions which are `inline` or `constexpr`  _are the same definition_, and thus are together _one_ definition, thus abiding by the spirit of the terminology.